# Right and Left click on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-event, android-gesture

How do i detect if i have clicked or press at right side of viewPager or at left side of viewPager.
I have tried with GestureDetector but couldn't make it out. 
Help me

Comment: Do you want to change current page by clicking on edges of the viewpager?

Comment: @aminography Yes. that's what i want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the GestureDetector to get SingleTapConfirmed Action

```
@Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            float x=e.getX()

            if(x < ( getWidth() * 0.5 )){
              //also check if item we set if valid or not i.e (getCurrentItem() - 1) > 0
              setCurrentItem( getCurrentItem() - 1)

            }else{
              //also check if item we set if valid or not i.e (getCurrentItem() + 1) < maxChildCount
              setCurrentItem( getCurrentItem() + 1)

            }

            return true;
        }
```

add this code in your custom ViewPager